# How can I expand on hover navigation drawer and use app bar icon on smaller screens?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to achieve to have my navigation drawer with `expand-on-hover` property true if i'm on desktop and show the classic `v-app-bar-nav-icon` if I'm on smaller screens or mobile.
I have done this but the behaviour is kinda weird:

```
<v-app-bar-nav-icon
    v-if="!drawer"
    @click="drawer = true"
></v-app-bar-nav-icon>

<v-navigation-drawer
  app
  dark
  :expand-on-hover="$vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndUp && drawer"
  v-model="drawer"
  style="background-color: #374A67"
></v-navigation-drawer>
```

Works but in some situations just broke and if I resize the window the navigation drawer push the app bar when is hovered giving me an empty space. How can I do this the right way? Thank you

Comment: How did you hover on mobile? 
Right It is possible only using input device like a mouse or touchpad

Comment: I'm not doing it, the `expand-on-hover` is deactivated in smaller screens. My question it's how to do it because it's not working properly the way I posted it.

Answer (score 5):

This will work perfectly.

```html
<v-navigation-drawer
  :value="$vuetify.breakpoint.smAndDown? drawer : true"
  app
  dark
  :expand-on-hover="$vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndUp"
  style="background-color: #374A67"
></v-navigation-drawer>
```

Comment: Just chiming in to say this worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: great!, it worked for me

Comment: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/display-and-platform/#breakpoints-and-thresholds

since Vuetify 3 these values have been moved to `$vuetify.display` Otherwise this solution still works